# setCompoundDrawable for TextView Align

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I've got a problem with setCompoundDrawable. I'm doing this programatically.

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
image.setBounds(0, 0, getLineHeight() * iconsize, getLineHeight() * iconsize);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setCompoundDrawable(null,null,image,null);
```

The problem is that the image is at the end like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
| Text                                           Image|
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the Image direct behind the text with a little bit of space.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

if `TextView` **width** fill the screen then image will go at the end **width** as `WRAP_CONTENT`

add `LayoutParams` for `TextView`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_icon = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can use this code for getting image behind text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Image"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

[image: myimage]

Comment: this is good for xml layouts thanks, but I do this with code. I'll keep it in mind :)